# How to change the chart of accounts (COA) in Odoo 10 or 9

Tags: odoo-9, odoo-10

I'd like to know what is the proper way to change the whole chart of accounts and import a new one in Odoo 10 or 9

P.s. we are using Enterprise version

**UPDATE:**

when I try to delete the following accounts I get this error

> You cannot remove/deactivate an account which is set on a customer or
>   vendor.

Here's the list of accounts:

- 101200 Account Receivable
- 101300 Tax Paid
- 111100 Account Payable
- 111200 Tax Received
- 200000 Product Sales
- 220000 Expenses

when I checked the log file I got this

```
odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "account_account" SET "code"='220000',"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (68)
```

any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are trying to delete accounts, it is already referenced on different places like Customers, Products, Taxes etc. So first you have to remove the references from all the places, then try deleting Chart of Accounts.

You have to enable debug mode to see below menus.
To remove all these reference for Partner and Products: 
Settings > Technical > Parameters > Company Properties and search for all these fields property_account_receivable_id, property_account_payable_id, property_account_income_categ_id, property_account_expense_categ_id. When you find records for these property fields open it and clear "Value" field data.

[Screenshot of Company Properties Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4P6L.jpg)

To remove from Taxes: 
Accounting > Configuration > Accounting > Taxes 
Open all the records and clear "Tax Account" and "Tax Account on Refunds" fields value.

To Remove from Journals:
Accounting > Configuration > Accounting > Journals
Open all the records and clear "Default Debit Account" and "Default Credit Account" fields value.

After doing above steps you will be able to delete Chart Of Accounts.

To import Chart of Accounts you have to first fill all the required fields like Code, Name, Internal Type and Allow Reconciliation. See below screenshot of the template

[COA Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jSqE.jpg)

Comment: when I tried to empty the fields values in customer's account, Odoo didn't allow me to leave those fields empty.. Therefore I had to remove these values from psql, only then I managed to delete these accounts from the chart .. my only worries now if what I've done would harm my database

Comment: You cannot clear those account fields in customer and supplier since it is a required field. No, it will not harm anything to your database but the good way to remove that from the property field value assignment in Company Properties and reassign new Account Value for default account assignment on the creation of the new Customer/ Supplier. Odoo does not recommend executing direct queries to database since they have already provided all the CRUD functions which take care of all the relations between all the objects.

Comment: Thank you Kav, I used your method and it worked perfectly. Now, do I need to update these deleted values in company properties after I upload a new COA? If yes, how do I get the correct value?

Comment: Welcome. If you want something to default when a Customer or Vendor gets created, then you have to set that value in company properties  otherwise you have to select manually each time. Please refer my previous attached screenshot of Company Properties Record for setting values.